# Is it possible to create a fuzzy controller with micropython?

Tags: python-3.x, microcontroller, micropython, fuzzy-logic, skfuzzy

I need to create a fuzzy controller with skfuzzy.

Is it possible to use skfuzzy to develop a fuzzy controller with [Micropython](https://github.com/micropython/micropython)?

https://github.com/scikit-fuzzy/scikit-fuzzy

Comment: Can you give any more detail about the requirements for your fuzzy controller? Have you already done something in desktop Python with skfuzzy? Yes, I'm sure it is possible to create a fuzzy controller with MicroPython, but without more detail nobody can advise you whether it's feasible for your application and your skill set.

Comment: Cpython and MicroPython are lighter implementations of Python (Due to hardware specification, etc.). Therefore, they do not support all python3 modules. That's it?

Comment: CPython is 'standard' Python. MicroPython is a lightweight implementation for microcontrollers. (CircuitPython, which I mentioned in another comment, is a fork of MicroPython.)

Comment: "Is it possible" questions are almost always far too broad.  And depending on your part, it might be utterly impossible.  Since you don't even mention the part you're using, it is impossible to answer.  Know how many microcontrollers there are?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general you're not going to be able to run any significant Python 3 code under MicroPython. While it's  "pretty close" to standard Python, the differences are enough to trip up anything other than  the simplest code.

The skfuzzy project to which you've linked depends on NumPy and SciPy, both of which are complex Python modules that depend extensively on compiled code to enhance performance. There's no chance those modules will (ever) run under MicroPython.

Comment: Would it be possible to create this fuzzy controller on the Raspberry Pi?

Comment: The Raspberry Pi is just a small desktop computer, so sure.

Comment: Would it be possible to create this fuzzy controller on the Arduino?

Comment: Is it possible to use all the features of python3 with arduino?

Comment: @Miltex To 'use all the features of python3' you need to run it on a computer with an operating system. This excludes all Arduino devices I know of. Some 32-bit Arduino devices may be able to run MicroPython, but I don't think there's pre-built firmware. You can run [CircuitPython](https://circuitpython.org/) on Arduino Zero devices; you can't run any kind of MicroPython on the original Arduino devices (Uno, etc.). A Uno could run a fuzzy controller written in C, but it sounds like that's beyond your current skills and knowledge. Please edit your question to explain your requirements better.

Comment: Cpython and MicroPython are lighter implementations of Python (Due to hardware specification, etc.). Therefore, they do not support all python3 modules. That's it?